# Joining two tables and then pulling non-matched records from a third table

Tags: sql, join, records

I have Visual Studio 2005 and am writing code in VB, not C+. I need a Select statement and have found some that are close but not for my situation. I have three tables:

```
PROJECT
    [Projnum]
    [ShipDate] 

CUSTOMER
    [Projnum]
    [Jobnum]

TAGS
    [Jobnum]
```

I need to join CUSTOMER and PROJECT so I know all the CUSTOMER.Jobnum records where PROJECT.ShipDate is null. Out of those records, I then need to get which ones do not have a match from TAGS.Jobnum.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks a bunch, Chuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.Jobnum
    FROM customer c
        INNER JOIN project p
            ON c.Projnum = p.Projnum
    WHERE p.ShipDate IS NULL
        AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM tags t WHERE t.Jobnum = c.Jobnum)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
PROJECT
  ProjNum
  ShipDate

CUSTOMER
  ProjNum
  JobNum

TAGS
  JobNum
```

And you want all unshipped projects:

```
SELECT c.JobNUm
FROM Project p
  INNER JOIN Customer c
    ON c.ProjNum = p.ProjNum
WHERE p.ShipDate is null
```

And then you want the ones without a JobNum in the TAGS table:

```
SELECT c.JobNUm
FROM Project p
  INNER JOIN Customer c
    ON c.ProjNum = p.ProjNum
WHERE p.ShipDate is null
  AND c.JobNum NOT IN (SELECT JobNum from TAGS)
```

Could be done simpler, but I wanted to show my work.

Answer (score 0):

A `LEFT JOIN` may be faster than `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS`.

```
SELECT c.JobNUm
FROM Project p
  INNER JOIN Customer c
    ON c.ProjNum = p.ProjNum
  LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.jobnum=c.jobnum
WHERE p.ShipDate is null AND t.jobnum IS NULL
```

Comment: The `NOT EXISTS` should be faster. See: [Left outer join vs NOT EXISTS](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/)

Comment: For several versions of Postgresql, `NOT EXISTS` had poor performance. I said *"may be faster"* because the relative speed will depend on the DB in use. I recommend the OP runs his RDBMS's explain (or equivalent) on real data before predicting whether the JOIN, the NOT EXISTS, or the NOT IN will be fastest.